# Buggy video tag

Tags: javascript, html

I spent 6 hours in hell trying to find what glitch causes my video to blink like that and as a second bug it just doesn't load. I literally freaked out :X
Here is what i tried until now:

http://jsfiddle.net/RhTTE/

MY js file, which I suspect may cause the problem:

```
$(document).ready(function (){

$('.play').click(function () {
    video = '<iframe width="600" height="375" frameborder="0" src="' + $('img').attr('data-video') + '"></iframe>';
    $('.video').replaceWith(video);
});
});

  var myVideo  = document.getElementById("video1");
  myVideo.style.marginLeft= "-20px";
  var menu = document.getElementById("menu");

function playPause()
{ 
if (myVideo.paused) 
  myVideo.play(); 
else 
  myVideo.pause(); 
} 
function makeBig()
{ 
myVideo.height=325;
myVideo.width=650;
myVideo.style.marginLeft= "-35px";
menu.style.width='650px';
menu.style.marginLeft= "-35px";
} 

function makeSmall()
{ 
myVideo.height=175;
myVideo.width=350;
myVideo.style.marginLeft= "-20px"; menu.style.width='350px';
menu.style.marginLeft= "115px";
} 

function makeNormal()
{ 
myVideo.height=250;
myVideo.width=500;
myVideo.style.marginLeft= "-20px"; menu.style.width='500px';
menu.style.marginLeft= "40px";
}
```

P.S. Somehow, it works properly on codepen's IDE.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend trying it without the <iframe. I believe there is generally a lot more happening when you instantiate an iframe and point it at a source than you may realize (security checks, etc). Try using the <video tag if its h264/webm/ogg

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem:
Firstly, as I tested iframe might not work properly combined with video tag in the same web page.
And secondly, the script tag's order was incorrect. I don't know why but it's place had to be after the video container's div.